# Connecting ends of edges openCV

Tags: python, opencv

My task is to determine the size of a bottle.

My sample images[image: My sample images]

Using gaussian blur, canny edged and dilate, erode, I have achieved this.

[image: Using gaussian blur, canny edged and dilate, erode, I have achieved this.]

Here's my code:

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
orig_image = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)
```

My question is how can I connect the ends of edges to get the bottles shape correctly in order to get its width and height?
And if possible ignore blobs outside like in the last image circled in blue.

Comment: Is the background of the images always black?

Comment: Yes, will use black side of a card board.

Comment: Try `convert to gray, threshold, apply morphology, then  get the outer contour by using CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE and RETR_EXTERNAL. Then get the bounding box coordinate from that contour.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest using a `line-detector` algorithm for finding the height of the each image in pixel.

---

1- Find the minimum y-coordinate (`y_min`) of the object.

2- Find the maximum y-coordinate (`y_max`) of the object.

3- Calculate the `y_max - y_min` for the approximate height.

---

An example:

Assume we have the following image, which is the second coke

[image]

- Image is resized to preserve space in the answer.

Using `createFastLineDetector` we can find the features of the image, for instance:

[image]

From the output, we need to find the minimum and the maximum y-coordinates:

[image]

So, from the output we can say, the approximate output is: `y_max - y_min`

[image]

If we try with other images:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("sprite.jpg")

orig_image = image.copy()
(h, w, c) = orig_image.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

lns = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(edged)

y_lists = []

for ln in lns:
    x1 = int(ln[0][0])
    y1 = int(ln[0][1])
    x2 = int(ln[0][2])
    y2 = int(ln[0][3])

    cv2.line(orig_image, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2),
             color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=5)

    print("Coords: ({}, {})->({}, {})".format(x1, y1, x2, y2))

    y_lists.append(y1)
    y_lists.append(y2)

y_min = min(y_lists)
y_max = max(y_lists)
cv2.circle(orig_image, (y_min, y_min), 20, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.putText(orig_image,
            '({}, {})'.format(y_min, y_min),
            (y_min - int(y_min/2), y_min - int(y_min/6)),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            4, (0, 0, 255), 6, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.circle(orig_image, (y_min, y_max), 20, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.putText(orig_image,
            '({}, {})'.format(y_min, y_max),
            (y_min - int(y_min/2), y_max + int(y_max/10)),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            4, (0, 0, 255), 6, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.line(orig_image, (y_min, y_min), (y_min, y_max),
         (0, 0, 255), 6, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(orig_image,
            '{} pixel'.format(y_max - y_min),
            (0, int(h/2)),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            4, (0, 0, 255), 6, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("result", orig_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

If I were you, I would also try @fmw42's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. `cv2.findContours()` - returns a vector of contours of the image, with `RETR_EXTERNAL` parameter (only external edges will be used for calculation)
2. Merge them all into a single vector of points
3. `cv2.convexHull()` will return a convex hull for the detected image
4. `cv2.boundingRect()` on the convex hull will return a rectangle with the width/height you want.

Another way to do it is to simply gather all coordinates that don't equal 0   into a (x, y) point list and run `cv2.convexHull` on them, then use `cv2.boundingRect` to get a rectangle.

Comment: Will experiment with this, then will get back to this comment. Very informative btw. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do that in Python/OpenCV. Simply convert to grayscale. Next threshold. Then get the array of y values of all the non-zero (white) pixels. Then from the array, get the min and may values. Then compute the height.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('coke_bottle2.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get the y coordinates of the white pixels
points = np.column_stack(np.nonzero(thresh))
print("points =")
print(points)
print("")

# get min_y max_y and height
print("")
min_y = np.amin(points, axis=0)[0]
print("min_y =", min_y)
print("")
max_y = np.amax(points, axis=0)[0]
print("max_y =", max_y)
print("")
height = max_y - min_y
print ("height = ", height)

cv2.imshow("GRAY", gray)
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Results:

points =
[[ 431  385]
[ 431  386]
[ 431  387]
...
[1313  455]
[1386  665]
[1387  665]]

min_y = 431
max_y = 1387

height =  956

Comment: This looks great, I'm trying it now.